# Apache not showing in /etc/services

Tags: apache-httpd, services

I've installed *apache2* on a server running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and it's current status is *running*. Shouldn't I be able to see that service also in the `/etc/services` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/services` is not a list of services currently running on your computer. It is not even a list of *possible* services on your or on any particular computer: not all services are listed in `/etc/services`, and implementations of some of the services listed in it might not even exist in your Linux distribution.

Instead, it is a mapping between port numbers and human-readable *port names*, for library routines like `getservent(3)`, `getservbyport(3)` and `getservbyport(3)`. Basically, it's a copy of (some version of) [IANA's master list of service names and port numbers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml), with possibly some distribution-specific additions, using a specific format that's directly usable by those library routines.

For example, if you run `netstat -a -A inet`, you may see some ports (typically the more well-known ones) identified by name, and the rest by number. If you add the `-n` option, the port-number-to-name mapping will be omitted and you will see all the port numbers as just numbers.

One of the very few places where it is/was the norm to use port names exclusively is the `/etc/inetd.conf` file for the classic `inetd` daemon. In modern software, you are either expected to just use port numbers, or can opt to use either names or numbers as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The service should be under :

```
/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service
```

[Writing_unit_files](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Writing_unit_files)

> /usr/lib/systemd/system/: units provided by installed packages

> /etc/systemd/system/: units installed by the system administrator

[systemd.unit manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/man5/systemd.unit.5.html)

Comment: So not all services are listed in `/etc/services`?

Comment: Perhaps they're looking for the "http" entry for port 80/tcp in /etc/services?